# how to use Nested rule

Tags: css, sass

```css
  @mixin text($color,$font-size){
   color:$color;
   font-size: $font-size;
 }

div{
  h3{
     @include text(#000,15px)
  }
}

div{
  h1{
   
    div > h3 @extend h3
  }
}
```

Here, I use one mixin class inside `div > h3` and next I want to use the same class in another `div > h1`. How can I use it?

Comment: can u plz send the html code?

Comment: Are you using .css or .scss? Because nesting css only works within .scss files.

Comment: sir i am using .scss in Angular 8

Comment: @Manikandan2811 sir i try to put my code here

Comment: @kalpesh ok.. but i need code structure to elaborate..